# Do courts withhold hearing transcripts from parties anywhere?

Tags: common-law, rules-of-court, court-records

Unlike the old days when court hearings were stenotyped, these days they just make audio recordings. Later those may be typed back to transcripts.

Anywhere in the world, do parties to court hearings have *no* absolute right to access those transcripts (or recordings), subject to any fee that may be required to cover the costs of typing them back? Can any court ever require parties to provide reasons why they want the transcripts, and decide whether to provide them — instead of providing them just on request?

(Any common law jurisdiction).

Comment: @bdb484 at the time when I made the comment, it was a *worldwide* question unbound to just common law. Not all legal systems do record and make transcripts, for example, traditional Sharia courts don't do any.

Comment: Worldwide questions seem fine to me. Correct me if I'm mistaken, but questions about comparative law are not off-topic.

Comment: they are not, but it is near impossible to prove a negative. Sure, you only need to find *one* case where it is true, but you can't prove a negative unless you limit the scope.

Comment: Your question largely covers this limitation, but in civil law countries, verbatim transcripts are generally no generated and are not used in appeals of first instance trials. If they are generated, they are solely for the convenience of the judges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[new-zealand](/questions/tagged/new-zealand)

It appears that in NZ courts of record there is no absolute right for parties to obtain hearing transcripts.

Upon a party requesting their hearing transcript, judges will ask to specify reasons, and may decline.

Eleven years after the government [launched](https://www.beehive.govt.nz/release/%E2%80%98real-time%E2%80%99-court-transcribing-launched) its virtually real-time National Transcription Service, in [*Nuku v R*](https://www.courtsofnz.govt.nz/assets/cases/2018/nqml.pdf), the applicant requested his transcript "for his own records and to assist him in his research and studies". [Winkelmann J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_Winkelmann) "did not see the reasons advanced by the applicant as warranting a direction that a transcript be **prepared**".
<sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

**Anywhere in the world, do parties to court hearings have *no* absolute right to access those transcripts (or recordings)?**

I have not checked every common law jurisdiction but I suspect that as all (?) such courts have their own inherent powers to make directions the answer is probably: **NO**.

That said, a *close-but-no-cigar* example may be found at [Rule 79.30](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part79#IDA5Z0IC) of the Civil Procedure Rules concerning terrorist financing proceedings in [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales):

> **Unless the court directs otherwise**, rule 5.4 (Register of Claims), rule 5.4B (Supply of documents from court records – a party) and rule 5.4C (Supply of documents from court records –a non-party) **do not apply** to any proceedings to which Section 2 or 3 of this Part applies or to any document relating to such proceedings.

"*Sections 2 and 3 of this Part*" refers to applications to set aside financial restrictions and appeals against being designated as being linked to terrorism.

The relevant cited Rules are:

> **5.4**
>
> (1) A court or court office may keep a publicly accessible register of claims which have been issued out of that court or court office.
>
> (2) **Any person** who pays the prescribed fee may, during office hours, search any available register of claims.

And

> **5.4B**
>
> (1) **A party to proceedings** may, unless the court orders otherwise, obtain from the records of the court a copy of any document listed in paragraph 4.2A of Practice Direction 5A.
>
> (2) A party to proceedings may, if the court gives permission, obtain from the records of the court a copy of any other document filed by a party or communication between the court and a party or another person.

Comment: There may be similar provisions in the E&W Criminal Procedure Rules, which I will research later.

Comment: Note that the question is about parties to proceedings only. Non-parties are not relevant, so could be skipped to shorten the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Anywhere in the world, do parties to court hearings have no absolute
> right to access those transcripts (or recordings), subject to any fee
> that may be required to cover the costs of typing them back? Can any
> court ever require parties to provide reasons why they want the
> transcripts, and decide whether to provide them — instead of providing
> them just on request?

Yes.

In common law countries, courts are divided between "courts of record" for which there is generally a right to a transcript (possibly subject to non-disclosure rules or limited access rules if the proceedings themselves are not public as in juvenile courts in the U.S. or the U.S. FISA court), and "courts not of record", in which any transcript is prepared for purposes other than an appeal.

Courts not of record typically are limited to petty criminal offenses and to civil cases with a small amount in controversy that does not involve title to real property. A very large share of their docket typically consists of accepting guilty pleas and entering default judgments in civil cases.

Even if proceedings of a court not of record are audio or video records, for example, in security camera footage, or for the convenience of the judge, there would be no right to access those recordings except for purposes such as cases where a crime is committed rather than merely tried, in the courtroom (e.g. a recent case in India where someone impersonating a lawyer from a rival gang murdered a criminal defendant in the courtroom).

In courts not of record, appeals are by trial de novo, rather than being based upon the trial court record, so there is no need to maintain an official transcript.

Comment: Guess you mean "petty criminal offenses", not "pretty".

Comment: In courts of record, can there be any legally valid reasons to withhold transcripts from parties?

Comment: @Greendrake 1. Typo fixed. Pretty criminal offenses are reserved for courts of general jurisdiction. 2. The exceptions are pretty narrow - there are some instances where that is true in the military tribunals at Gitmo which are organized as tribunals of record, and with respect to some parties in the FISA court. In those cases, counsel with security clearances can see them but parties without security clearances can't.

Comment: I suppose that small claims courts are usually courts not of record, is this correct?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Local practice on whether small claims courts are courts of record or not varies significantly from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. For example, in Colorado, the only courts currently not of record are municipal courts which are limited to enforcement of municipal ordinances and are not part of the state court system. In New York State, in contrast, Justices of the Peace proceedings are not courts of records and handle both petty offenses and small claims. The decision hinges primarily on the organizational structure and administrative capacity of the judicial branch bureaucracy.

Answer (score 1):

In the United Kingdom, in some unusual circumstances, a court or tribunal can exclude a party and their representatives from part of the hearing. This is usually where evidence is to be heard which would harm national security if it became public and the interests of the excluded party are typically represented by a "special advocate".

Where a party is excluded in these circumstances the excluded party cannot, of course, obtain a transcript of the part of the hearing they were excluded from.